# How can I replace eval?

Tags: python

How can I replace eval? I was reading a lot of information about bad experience using it

```
 class vahicle():
    def move(class):
         cl = eval(class)
         # i need to use car as class here
 class car(vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
           pass
    def movement():
        name = self.class.name
        move(self, name)
```

Comment: In python you can pass classes and function directly, you don't need to pass the name of the function and eval that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve anyway? Why does `car.movement` call `vehicle.move` with it's own class name as a parameter? There might be a better and entirely different way do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Vehicle():

    def move(self, cls):
        return cls()

class Car(Vehicle):

    def movement(self):
        return self.move(self.__class__)

c = Car()
print c.movement()
```

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been answered use class methods for your task and pass a class object to it.

If are asking about alternative to `eval()` in python since it's not secure, you can use `ast.literal_eval()` instead.